# Unable to open flutter project on android studio after upgrade

Tags: android-studio, dart, flutter

Yesterday I've upgraded my Windows 7 SP1 Powershell from 2 to 5.1, and upgraded flutter and dart to latest version using the `flutter upgrade` command, all worked fine, and I continued working as normal. Today after trying to access my project again I got a couple of errors, and all of my project structure gone. What can I do? and why that happened? Was that due to the upgrade? or something else?

```
Load Settings
Cannot load settings from file 'C:\Users\user\Documents\FlutterProjects\project\android\project_android.iml': ParseError at [row,col]:[1,1]
Message: Content is not allowed in prolog.
Please correct the file content

Load Settings
Cannot load settings from file 'C:\Users\user\Documents\FlutterProjects\project\project.iml': ParseError at [row,col]:[1,1]
Message: Content is not allowed in prolog.
Please correct the file content
```

Comment: Did you try `flutter clean`?

Comment: Just did, didn't seem to do anything, just deleted the build file, restarted the studio and still same errors

Comment: @JimmyBower same for me on different projects. Every time I open a project that worked yesterday I get similar error to yours. No idea. By the way I did not use powershell, I use android studio. You can fix the project by reimporting, bus the flaw remains every time you close and open again

Answer (score 24):

Just delete .idea folder from project directory an re run android studio. it worked for me.

Comment: Definitely the best solution in all aspects. This one should be the right answer.

Comment: Worked for me, should be at top.

Comment: It worked, thanks, man. This should be the answer.

Answer (score 21):

The problem is caused by `<projectname>.iml` inside the root project folder.

1. First cut the file from the folder and paste it somewhere else
2. Restart Android Studio
3. Close it again and put `<projectname>.iml` back into the root folder
4. Restart Android Studio once again

Comment: Wow man, you saved my time for starting new project, and copying files from old project folder to new. I dont know why this happends.

Answer (score 0):

simply cut the (PORJNAME).iml into the desktop and re-run the IDE or android studio.
after re-running close the ide again and move back the (PORJNAME).iml to their own place,
and open the ide

Comment: this was already provided as a solution by @akshay yadav

Answer (score 0):

Don't delete or rename any file in your project
but when you update flutter, you must have compatible version from other plugins and dependencies with your new version, so
do this steps and run again it will be ok:-

1- Close android studio and open it again

2- From terminal tab down in android studio run (flutter clean)

3- From terminal also run  (flutter doctor)

4- Then run (flutter doctor -v)

5- After all at last run (pub outdated)

6- Close android studio and restart

7- Run your project and enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

You can just go to your extensions tab on vscode search for dart and later for flutter and click on the Switch to Release Version Button.

reloading your version is required after this fix.

[Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ykWxr.png)